# Math operation between variables always return zero

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this function as follows:

```
private int Calc_bmi(int userid, int wt, int ht) {
    int bmi = ((wt / ht) / ht) * 10000;
}
```

The values of variables `wt` and `ht` are correct. I also tried it with using `float bmi` and also using `Convert.ToInt32` but it doesn't seem to work. It returns 0 every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: int div int is int. Better cast to float before. Looks like a duplicate.

Comment: @UweKeim how do I convert it then?

Comment: @UweKeim do I need to convert wt and ht to float ?

Comment: What are your units?  Integer division just gives you the whole number result (no remainder) of the division.  For example, 5/3 results in 1.  Divide it by 3 again and you get 0.  Why are you using ints and not floats or decimals

Comment: To convert them, do this: `(((double)wt/ht) /ht)`.  If you divide a floating point number by an integer, you get a floating point number

Comment: Before convert nothing, I would check why it returns 0 every time... I imagine wt=4 and ht=2, and of course, the result of your operation is not 0 (4 / 2 = 2 / 2 = 1 * 10000 = 10000 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert `wt` and `ht` to float:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      int bmi = Calc_bmi(12, 10, 20);
      Console.WriteLine(bmi);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static int Calc_bmi(int userid, int wt, int ht)
    {
      float fWt = (float)wt;
      float fHt = (float)ht;
      float bmi = ((fWt / fHt) / fHt) * 10000;
      return Convert.ToInt32(bmi);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You only really need to convert one of them, but...